# Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial with real coefficients and leading coefficient 1

Tags: polynomials, roots, upper-lower-bounds

> Let $p(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+....+a_0$ be a polynomial with real coefficients and leading coefficient of $1$. Let $M_1=1+max (|a_0|,|a_1|,|a_2|,...,a_{n-1}|)$ and Let $M_2=max (1,|a_0|+|a_1|+|a_2|...+|a_{n-1}|)$. Finally let $M=(M_1,M_2)$.

Then prove that every zero of $p(x)$ lies between $-M$ and $M$.

I approached this problem by induction but it was just a mess.
So how do I proceed??

Comment: Check out the proofs here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_properties_of_polynomial_roots#Lagrange%27s_and_Cauchy%27s_bounds. The idea is to assume $x$ is a zero, then use triangle inequality and other coarse bounds to bound $x$.